North arrow rotation around anchor points non-functional in ArcGIS Pro
In ArcGIS Pro 3.2 is there a way to get the north arrow anchor points to operate like they did in ArcGIS Desktop?  From what I am seeing, the north arrow rotates around the anchor point, rather than rotating within a box that has the corner location locked at the anchor point.  So instead of doing this (which is actually useful):

It does this:

Is there any way to approximate the functionality of the Desktop setup? In the context of layouts with map series and rotating map frames, I can't imagine the way that Pro does it ever making sense using anything other than an approximately square compass anchored in the center.  There is just no way to get my rectangular arrow to stay put and line up in a way that doesn't look out of place when the maps rotate.
